# About a deep header file in Makefile

Tags: makefile

Say I have a header file which is included by many source files, maybe with a very deep hierarchy. It is very boring to list this common header file in the prerequisites of each source object, and not sure whether there is an elegant solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate such dependencies with `gcc -M`.  From [TFM](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-M-954):

`-M Instead of outputting the result of preprocessing, output a rule suitable for make describing the dependencies of the main source file. The preprocessor outputs one make rule containing the object file name for that source file, a colon, and the names of all the included files, including those coming from -include or -imacros command line options.`

Also see [Generating Prerequisites Automatically](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html).